# Combinations of people on a committee

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Unsure about my answers:

```
  Eight people, including Mary and Peter, are candidates to serve on a committee of five.
    (a) How many different committees are possible?
    (b) How many different committees are there that contain both Mary and Peter?
    (c) How many different committees are there that contain neither Mary nor Peter?
    (d) How many different committees are there that contain either Mary or Peter or possibly
    both of them?
    (e) How many different committees are there that contain just one of Mary or Peter?
```

For part a, I got 8C5 (8 choose 5) = 56

For part b, 6C3 = 20

For part c, 8C5-6C3 = 36

For part D and E, I've no ideas.
Would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first two answers are fine. Your answer for (c), however, is wrong: $\binom85-\binom63$ is the number of committees that do not contain *both* Mary and Peter, including those that contain just one of these two people. The committees that contain neither Mary nor Peter must be formed from the other $6$ people, so there are $\binom65=6$ of them.

To answer (d), look at the complementary set of committees, i.e., the set of committees that *don’t* satisfy the given condition. These are the committees that contain neither Mary nor Peter, and we just saw that there are $6$ of them. Every other possible committee contains Mary or Peter or both, and since there are $56$ possible committees (as we know from (a)), there must be $56-6=50$ committees that contain Mary or Peter or both.

Finally, to answer (e) you need only combine the answers to (b) and (d) in the appropriate way; do you see how?

Comment: Many thanks. For part e, I think you'd take the no. of committees which take both and subtract from either-or/both leaving with just either-or. This would be 50 -  20 = 30    . Is this correct?

Comment: @ak1652: Yes, that’s correct. You’re welcome.